# $(\sum_{n=1}^{100} n!)^7$ is of the form $7k+5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Could any one just check for me that $(\sum_{n=1}^{100} n!)^7$ is of the form $7k+5$ or not? I got it that but they asked me to show it is of the form $7k+4$

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $\displaystyle r!\equiv0\pmod7 $ for $r\ge7$

$\displaystyle\implies \sum_{n=1}^{100} n!\equiv\sum_{n=1}^6 n!\pmod7 $

Now, using Wilson's Theorem, $\displaystyle6!\equiv-1\pmod 7$

As $\displaystyle 6\equiv-1\pmod7, $

$\displaystyle5!\equiv (-6)\cdot5!\pmod7\equiv-(6!)\equiv-(-1)\equiv1$

The rest terms are small enough to be handled directly

Comment: Another way : $5!+6!=5!(1+6)\equiv0\pmod 7$

Comment: @miosaki, Have you understood my method?

Comment: @miosaki, please use lingua franca. If you have understood the method, you should be able to calculate

Comment: I wrote wrong question, I have edited my question. could you do it now fully?

Comment: @miosaki, if you know $$\sum_{n=1}^{100} n!=a\pmod 7,$$  $$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{100} n!\right)^7=a^7\pmod 7,$$  Now use Fermat's Little Theorem : $a^7\equiv a\pmod 7$

Comment: no I dont know...

Comment: @miosaki, I'm really feeling sorry that I could not make understand the method. Wish I knew where your are stuck